# Why can't a Queueable use an Iterator that comes from a Set?

Tags: queueable-apex, iteration

I saw some surprising behaviour when storing the iterator obtained from a `Set<Id>` as a member in a `Queueable` class. So, I wrote the following trivial `Queueable` class to investigate:

```
public class QueueableWithIterators implements Queueable {

    public static List<String> results = new List<String>();
    private Iterator<String> myIterator;

    public QueueableWithIterators(Iterator<String> myIterator) {
        this.myIterator = myIterator;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext param1) {
        results.add(myIterator.next());
        if(myIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.enqueueJob(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that this `Queueable` will exhaust the iterator, putting values onto a static list so that we can see the results in an Apex test.

Then I wrote a couple of tests:

```
@IsTest
private class QueueableWithIteratorsTest {

    @IsTest
    static void setVersion() {
        Test.startTest();
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableWithIterators(new Set<String>{'a'}.iterator()));
        Test.stopTest();

        Assert.areEqual(1, QueueableWithIterators.results.size());
        Assert.areEqual('a', QueueableWithIterators.results[0]);
    }

    @IsTest
    static void listVersion() {
        Test.startTest();
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableWithIterators(new List<String>{'a'}.iterator()));
        Test.stopTest();

        Assert.areEqual(1, QueueableWithIterators.results.size());
        Assert.areEqual('a', QueueableWithIterators.results[0]);
    }
}
```

Running these tests, the `List` version passes but the `Set` version fails. More than that, by looking at the code coverage state, we can see that the `Set` version doesn't even run the `execute()` method.

If I try to run this code in Anonymous Apex, the `List` version completes and the `Set` version job just gets stuck in `Processing` status and never runs.

This smells like a bug, but is it a known issue (I couldn't find it) or a misunderstanding on my part?

NB, This is running in a Spring 23 scratch org.

Comment: Thanks for raising this. I suspect a serialization issue, but I'm following up with Apex engineering to get to the exact root cause.

Comment: Thank you so much!